# Using camera in Android without launching camera app

Tags: android, camera

I want an Activity which basically shows the view of the camera without opening the camera app.

I'm wondering do I need to control drivers at a much lower level for this?

Ideally I'd like if the camera view filled the screen with my own image covering it (like binoculars). As you probably guessed it is for a game I'm making.

All the tutorials online seem to talk about opening the default camera app.

Here's an image I found online which displays what I'm asking for:

[image]

If anyone knows any tutorials, links, books, forums, anything which deals with this specifically it would be very helpful.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Perckory : are you talking about implementing custom camera ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can operate camera in your app directly without know any hardware driver.

The general steps for creating a custom camera interface for your application are as follows:

- Detect and Access Camera - Create code to check for the existence of cameras and request access.
- Create a Preview Class - Create a camera preview class that extends SurfaceView and implements the SurfaceHolder interface. This class previews the live images from the camera.
- Build a Preview Layout - Once you have the camera preview class, create a view layout that incorporates the preview and the user interface controls you want.
- Setup Listeners for Capture - Connect listeners for your interface controls to start image or video capture in response to user actions, such as pressing a button.
- Capture and Save Files - Setup the code for capturing pictures or videos and saving the output.
- Release the Camera - After using the camera, your application must properly release it for use by other applications.

Check out Android's guide on how to write Camera app: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html

Note: newer app should use *android.hardware.camera2* API

Comment: Of course. I should've tried Android developer site first. Nice summary though !